# Create Report for Google Cloud Platform of Individual Users

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I am trying to understand my options for creating a report in GCP to identify individual user accounts assigned to resources (Org, Folders, projects, Billing Accounts, VPC) inside of my GCP Resource Hierarchy. I would assume this question has been answered but I am unable to find any information on this.

Please let me know if this is the correct forum to ask this type of question or if I need to put this question in one of the other forums. 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually complicated to do in Google Cloud.

There are two areas that you want to track. IAM members and IAM members assigned to resources.

There are a number of IAM member types: users, services accounts, groups, G Suite domains, Cloud Identity domains.

Some resources can be assigned IAM members. An example would be for impersonation or ActAs. You will need to scan every resource that supports member assignment.

To add to this there are assigned members and inherited members.

Then there are organizations, folders and projects.

If your goal is to simply create a report for auditing, buy a commercial product or service. There are many to choose from.

If your goal is to develop a deeper understanding of Google IAM, resources, roles and permissions, select your favorite language and dig into the Google Cloud SDK and the Google Cloud CLI `gcloud`.

Comment: Based on my research, this is what I thought. It is overly complicated for something I would think to be simple. I guess I have some coding to do. Thanks for information

Answer (score 0):

[The `asset` command](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/quickstart) of the `gcloud` command line tool can be used to gather the data you are looking for. Before starting, [ensure that you have the correct IAM permissions to view assets](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/configuring-permissions).  If you have multiple projects under one org, this command can gather all IAM policies from the org and all projects in the org's hierarchy:

```
gcloud asset export --content-type iam-policy --organization your-org-id \
--output-path gs://your-secure-bucket/your-policy-audit
```

The policy file is saved as a text file to a Google Cloud Storage bucket. The file consists of multiple JSON objects, one per line. You'll still have to process the IAM file to extract the users.